# AOMDV in NS2.34 Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

I use AOMDV NS2.34. I have generated a CBR file and a mobility scene file with pause time 0 (highly dynamic environment). When I run the wireless.tcl with AOMDV with the generated traffic and scene files, I always get segmentation fault.

If I try to run a static mobility scene file (pause time = simulation time), I get everything working normally.

Does anyone find problem in AOMDV provided with ns2.34? If yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @DonalFellows I do not understand what a stack trace is. I assume, I do not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use the aomdv.tcl file already provided in the tcl/ex folder of ns2. In this file, I can change the minPausTime and maxPauseTime based on my needs instead of using a pre-defined CBR file.